# How to use JavaScript to set an attribute if a condition exists?

Tags: javascript, html

In the snippet below, I'm creating an array of all panels and all links within those panels.

Then, for each panel with the class of active, I want all the links to be set to `tabindex="0"`. For all other links, I want `tabindex="-1"`.

In my example, I don't understand why all links are set to `tabindex="-1"`, when one of the panels has the active class. Why isn't it set to `tabindex="0"`?

```js
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.panel a');
panels.forEach(function(panel) {
  if (panel.classList.contains('active')) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, link => link.setAttribute('tabindex', '0'))
  } else {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, link => link.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1'))
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="panels">
  <div class="panel active">
    <p>Hello <a href="#">World</a>. I am <a href="#">with</a> you.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Hello <a href="#">World</a>. I am <a href="#">with</a> you.</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: It probably is set to 0 momentarily, but then is overwritten the next time you loop and find a panel which isn't active. Your code doesn't target the links within a specific panel when it sets the attribute, it just sets all of them regardless.

Comment: You don't need `Array.prototype.forEach.call`. `NodeList` implements `forEach`.

Comment: Ok. How do you suppose I get to the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Move `const links = document.querySelectorAll('.panel a');` into the loop and change to `const links = panel.querySelectorAll('a');` ?

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp. That was it.

Comment: @ADyson How would I target the links within a specific panel, as you suggested? My goal is to target all links within any panel. I'm asking because now everything's a bit buggy. This tabindex I'm trying to apply doesn't work all the time now.

Comment: `How would I target the links within a specific panel`...what Johnny Mopp suggested should be one way to do it. What do you mean by "everything's a bit buggy"? That's not a specific problem we can fix. If you need further help the best thing to do is edit your question to show your latest code, and explain clearly and specifically what behaviour you're seeing, compared to what you expected.